# Is Mahabali still the ruler in charge of Sutala?

Tags: vamana

As we know there are fourteen Lokas.
And Mahabali was made King of Sutala by Lord Visnu's Avatar, Lord Vamana and Lord also promised to make him Indra.
So I wanted to know if his time in Sutala has come to an end.

Comment: No, it hasn't.  He will continue to be the ruler of Sutalaloka for the rest of the Vaivasvata Manvantara.  Ravana and Krishna encountered him in Sutalaloka.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan why not answer it

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan when did Ravana and Krishna encountered Mahabali and how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in [What is the life span of the people who are living in lower planetary systems (from Atala to Patala lokas)?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/35788/what-is-the-life-span-of-the-people-who-are-living-in-lower-planetary-systems-f/35794#35794) post, Sutala comes under **बिलस्वर्ग (subterranean heaven)** and fear of old age and death is not there.

Also, **SB 8.22.32** mention:

> Until Bali Mahārāja achieves the position of King of heaven, he shall live on the planet Sutala.

As per [Vishnu Purana](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/22693/12304) and many other sources, Bali Mahārāja would become Indra (post for king of Devas/heaven) in next i.e. 8th Manvantara.

---

Related posts

[Who is the current leader of Asuras?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/16197/who-is-the-current-leader-of-asuras/31596#31596)

[What will happen to Hanuman and the other Chiranjivis after the end of the Kali Yuga?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/22680/what-will-happen-to-hanuman-and-the-other-chiranjivis-after-the-end-of-the-kali/22693#22693)